# Google PubSub's unacked messaged not getting pulled by the client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a very simple Node.js application that is subscribed to a pub/sub topic. I have set the ack deadline to 10seconds on the cloud console.

```
const client = new PubSub()
const sub = client.subscription('my-topic-sub')

sub.on("message", (msg) => {
  console.log("msg received")
})
```

When I publish a message to the topic it gets received by the node app and the log is printed but since I don't ack the message I expect it to be re-delivered and the log to print again.

I have tried fiddling with the settings and pass the ackDeadline option directly to the subscription through code but no effect. The interesting thing is that if I nack the message it gets redelivered instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the client library extends the ack deadline of an unacknowledged message for an hour, which would prevent the redelivery of the message. See the [lease management documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/lease-management) for more information. You can change the length of time for which the deadline is extended by changing the maximum acknowledgement extension period:

```
const options = {
  flowControl: {
    maxExtensionMinutes: 1,
  }
};

const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription('my-topic-sub', options);
```